# How to open xlsx files stored in a folder one by one and copy data to another file using JAVA

Tags: java

I wants to open xlsx files stored in a folder (one by one) and copy that sheet data column by column (if column name matches) to another file stored in other folder.
Column name mapping data is stored in a sheet.

Suppose sheet 1 contains column name mapping. using this mapping, I want to copy data of each column from each sheet stored in a particular folder to another file stored in another folder.

I tried with this code given below, but I am able to read and write compare headers, but I am unable to read from file one by one.
Code:

```
    public class Read {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

         //Create blank workbook
         HSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook(); 

         HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook1.createSheet("  Info ");
         //Create row object
         // HSSFRow row1;

         ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
         Read read = new Read();
         String x ="Name";
         //int columnIndex = 0;
         lst = read.extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(x);

         //int rowid = 0;

         //row1 = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
         //Object [] objectArr = empinfo.get(key);
         //int cellid = 0;
         //int i=0;
         for(int RowNum=0; RowNum<lst.size();RowNum++){
             HSSFRow row1 = spreadsheet.createRow(RowNum);
             for(int ColNum=0; ColNum<1;ColNum++){
                 HSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(ColNum);
                 cell.setCellValue(lst.get(RowNum).toString()); 
             }
         }

         //Write the workbook in file system
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Writesheet.xls"));
         // System.out.println(lst);
         workbook1.write(out);
         out.close();   
     }


     public  ArrayList<String> extractExcelContentByColumnIndex( String colName)
     {
         ArrayList<String> columndata = null;
         int columnIndex= 0;
         int flag=0;
         try {
             File f = new File("abc.xlsx");
             FileInputStream ios = new FileInputStream(f);
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ios);

             XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
             Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
             columndata =  new ArrayList<String>();

             while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                 Row row = rowIterator.next();
                 Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                 while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                     Cell cell1 = cellIterator.next();
                     String temp=cell1.getStringCellValue().toString();
                     //System.out.println(temp);
                     if(temp.equals(colName)){
                         columnIndex=cell1.getColumnIndex();
                         flag=1;
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 if(flag==1)
                 {
                     flag = 0;
                     break;
                 }
             }
             while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                 Row row = rowIterator.next();
                 // System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
                 Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                 while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                     Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                     if(row.getRowNum() > 0){ 
                         //To filter column headings
                         if(cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex){
                             // To match column index
                             switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                     columndata.add(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"");
                                     break;
                                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:                                                                                 
                                     columndata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                     break;
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
             ios.close();
             System.out.println(colName);   
             for(String ele : columndata){
                 System.out.println(ele);        
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return columndata;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading files one by one you can use `java.io.File.listFiles()` method.

> The method returns the array of abstract pathnames defining the
>   files in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname.

Sample code

```
 File folder = new File(path / up / to / folder);
 File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

 for (File file: listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().contains(".xlsx")) {
    // if you want to read only xlsx files
    // Your logic
    }
}
```